# Make the span positioned in the last line of P

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on the layout.
I need to put an external span element to the last line of p

```
<p>I am here I am here I am here I am here I am here I am here </p><span>same line of the last line of paragraph </span>
```

Are there any CSS properties to archive it?

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qm3pe/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

and

```
p{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

won't work if the p element is longer than one line. I recommend

```
p{
display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css to the `p` tag

```
p{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Working Code:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/2aVpD/7/)